# Connect using web proxy to allow OAuth to work

Tags: proxy, sitecore, facebook-oauth, sitecore7.1, sitecore-social-connected

I'm running Sitecore.NET 7.0 (rev. 140120) with Social Connected 2.0 (for CMS 7.0).

However - unfortunately our corporate environment requires us to connect via a proxy server, so currently my dev environment does not work.

I reflected the code in `Sitecore.Social.Facebook.dll` and can see the code in `Sitecore.Social.Facebook.Connector.Managers.WebRequestManager.GetResponse()` that makes the HTTP requests to facebook.com, and which does not appear to reference a proxy.

I have confirmed on another network without proxy requirements that my setup works well.

Is there a way to specify a proxy for such requests? Can I write my own replacement which will allow a proxy to be configured - if so how do I plug this in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution ended up being pretty simple. I added the following into my web.config:

```
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="true">
    </defaultProxy>
  </system.net>
```

You can also specify other proxy configuration using this method which will affect your whole web application.

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kd3cf2ex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)